# Layer converted into attribute

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, attribute-table, merge

[image]I am using QGIS 3.8. I am creating a geological map, and because I wanted to merge two different polygons, it created a separate layer. I want to convert this dissolved layer into the attribute to my geology layer with the other polygons. Sorry for my english termology, I'm not an experienced user. Can you help me?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a few screenshots of your polygon layers and the attribute table you mention? It's a little unclear exactly what your problem is and what you're aiming for based on your question.

Comment: Do you want to copy the categorized attribute-based style from the original layer to the new one? You can copy a style by right clicking on the original layer name in the layer panel > style > copy style > all. Then repeat the process with the new layer except choose "paste style."